# Django Rest Framework Custom Object Permission is not Called

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

So, i want to make endpoints where Anon or non-admin can only POST.
The endpoints are:

- api/v1/keywords/
- api/v1/keyword/$id

I already made the custom permission and apply it into the class-based views.

```
#permissions.py
from rest_framework import permissions

class AnonWriteOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Anon can only post
    """
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        # Only allow post request
        allowed_methods = ('POST')  
        if request.method in allowed_methods:
            print (True) #debugging purpose
            return True
        print(False) #debugging purpose
        return permissions.IsAuthenticated.has_permission(self, request, view)
```

This is my views:

```
# Anon can post.

#Corresponds to the first endpoint
class KeywordList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    List all keywords, or create a new keyword
    """
    permission_classes = [AnonWriteOnly]
    queryset = Keyword.objects.all()   
    serializer_class = KeywordSerializer

#Corresponds to the second endpoint
class KeywordDetail(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    """
    Retrieve, update, delete keyword
    """
    permission_classes = [AnonWriteOnly]
    queryset = Keyword.objects.all()
    serializer_class = KeywordSerializer
```

When I am not logged in and try to open the second endpoint, it works fine. It has 403 response, the output is also printed.

```
False
[27/May/2018 18:14:33] "GET /api/v1/keyword/1 HTTP/1.1" 403 10621
```

But, when I try to open the first endpoint it doesn't print anything, it is just run normally, without permission.

```
[27/May/2018 18:28:02] "GET /api/v1/keywords/ HTTP/1.1" 200 13256
```

I have tried to change the permissions.IsAuthenticated to permissions.IsAdminUser but still, no luck.

But, it works fine by overriding the has_permission

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class AnonWriteOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Anon can only post
    """
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # Only allow post request
        allowed_methods = ('POST')  
        if request.method in allowed_methods:
            print (True)
            return True
        print(False)
        return request.user.is_staff
```

Why does it not working with has_object_permission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is two things:

```
allowed_methods = ('POST',)
```

you forget comma (if there is not comma it is just string, but if there is comma it is tuple)

has_object_permissions - DRF calls it when you want to get the object, not create object.

Comment: So we can't use has_object_permission when passing POST request?
Thanks :)

Comment: POST uses for create objects, so yes, it is has_permissions, not has_object_permission